# jQuery hoverIntent for only one div class when the class is being used multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I am using the jQuery hoverIntent plugin to fade in a div when another div is being hovered over.  There are 4 elements that share a class name, and I only want to fade in the children of the element I am hovering over, not every div that shares the class' children.  The problem now is if I hover over one dive it fades in all 4 elements children.  Where in my code little bit of code have I gone wrong?

Here's the html:

```html
<div id="resources" class="faded">

<div class="resourcesHover"></div>

</div>

<div id="forBuilders" class="faded">

<div class="buildersHover"></div>

</div>

<div id="fam" class="faded">

<div class="famHover"></div>

</div>

<div id="homePlans" class="faded">

<div class="plansHover"></div>

</div>
```

Here's the jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".faded").hoverIntent({
    over:    fadeDivIn,
    timeout: 300,
    out:     fadeDivOut
});

function fadeDivIn() {
    var $kids = $('.faded').children();
    $($kids, this).fadeIn('slow');
}

function fadeDivOut() {
    var $kids = $('.faded').children();
    $($kids, this).fadeOut('slow');
}

});
```

**Just in case anyone has a similar issue, I figured out the solution and posted it below.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out.  I added a `this,` to the line that sets the children into a variable, and also removed it from the .fadeIn and .fadeOut lines.

Here's the new jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".faded").hoverIntent({
    over:    fadeDivIn,
    timeout: 300,
    out:     fadeDivOut
});

function fadeDivIn() {  
    var $kids = $(this,'.faded').children();
    $($kids).fadeIn('slow');
}

function fadeDivOut() {
    var $kids = $(this,'.faded').children();
    $($kids).fadeOut('slow');
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `fadeDivIn` and `fadeDivOut` functions as follows:

```
function fadeDivIn() {
    var $kids = $(this).children();
    $($kids).fadeIn('slow');
}

function fadeDivOut() {
    var $kids = $(this).children();
    $($kids).fadeOut('slow');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  I had previously had it that way, but it does nothing at all.  I tried it again just to make sure though.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your fade in and fade out functions, you need to select `this` instead of all elements of the class `faded`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".faded").on('mouseover', function() {
    fadeDivIn(this);
});

$(".faded").on('mouseout', function() {
    fadeDivOut(this);
});

function fadeDivIn(hovered_over) {
    var $kids = $(hovered_over).children();
    $($kids).fadeIn('slow');
}

function fadeDivOut(hovered_over) {
    var $kids = $(hovered_over).children();
    $($kids).fadeOut('slow');
}

});
```

Comment: When you do `over: fadeDivIn(this)` it actually calls the function and stores its return value in the propert named `over` instead of setting a callback handler.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this does not work either.  As soon as the page loads all for divs fade in and right out.  I copied your code directly from here to verify I didn't have a typo as well.

Comment: That works to an extent.  When you hover hover the element, in fades in then out then in again.  I see that with that code you are no longer utilizing the hoverIntent plugin also.  I would much prefer to use the hoverIntent plugin along with it so to minimize accidentally triggering the hover.